# Using vue-i18n.t() inside computed warning

Tags: vuejs3, vue-i18n

After upgrading my project I'm getting this warning for every time I try to use VueI18n.t() inside computed varaibles:

```
[Vue warn]: getCurrentInstance() called inside a computed getter. This is incorrect usage as computed getters are not guaranteed to be executed with an active component instance. If you are using a composable inside a computed getter, move it ouside to the setup scope.
```

This is be a minimal example of it being triggered

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import { computed } from 'vue'

const { t } = useI18n()
const props = defineProps<{
  infot: string
}>()

const label = computed(() => t(props.infot))
</script>
```

libraries versions:

```
"vue": "^3.4.6",
"vue-i18n": "^9.9.0",
"vite": "^5.0.11",
"@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.2",
"typescript": "^5.3.3",
```

I've tried using the global $t() but obviously it didn't work.

```
const label = computed(() => $t(props.infot))
```

The warning goes away if I define the variable as a function and call it like this:

```
function label() { return t(props.infot) }
```

or if I define it as a composable and use it like this

```
const { label } = translateLabel(toRef(props, 'infot'))
```

I don't like the previous solutions because in the [VueI18n documentation](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html#message-translation) they use t() inside computed variables without problems. And having to change all the occurrencies inside the codebase would be kinda taxing. Am I missing something? Anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just upgrade vue to v3.4.7. That should fix your problem.

For more informations : https://github.com/vuejs/core/discussions/9974

Comment: That solved it, memo for next time check the discussions tab too and not only the issues tab in the git repo. 
Thank you